# Cost effective and timely system to do Business Logic queries (batch processing) on weekly snapshots of a 15 gb MySQL database?

Tags: elasticsearch, hive, bigdata

We want to do batch operations on a series of MySQL snapshots, but are unsure of what architecture to purseu.  We have over 100 snapshots of a 15 gb database.

We are currently debating what architecture to use that wouldn't be embarrassing slow, but not huge overhead (time-wise or monetarily).  Here is what we have considered:

Loading each db into a Open stack VM doing our query then saving the data found off somewhere in a Redis Instance where we can use python to dump the reports.  (This would be slow no?)

Loading everything into elastic search and perform queries via elastic search (This would not allow the robustness/logic of querying we want.)

We have looked at Hive or prestodb but that would require large amounts of hardware?

On a small scale some of our tables look like this:

```
    client:
        client_id (primary key)
        name
        address
        city

    device:
        device_id (primary key)
        name
        location

    service:
        service_id (primary key)
        name
        price
        client_id
        device_id

    (there are no relationships between tables)
```

Here is an example of what we want to do:

Look at all the services that have increased in price over the last month of snapshots (4 snapshots).  Get the client's location of client and device name for each service that increased.  Dump it to a csv or some other visualizing software like kibana.

Comment: Not sure what "there are no relationships between tables" means when `service` clearly has two foreign keys to the other two tables. Also why do you say that "ES would not allow the robustness of querying you want?" It's pretty easy to index those tables into a single ES mapping type and then run the query you're after.

Comment: 15GB is a fairly small db and why you have 100 snapshots of it? Most likely regular SQL should be fine, have a read-only replica to reduce load on the production server. Sounds like you need someone to help you.

Comment: @Val They have no foreign key.  They are just Integer fields that "could" correlate with another tables primary key.  There is no actual link in the database.   And please correct me if I am wrong, would we be able to do the example query via elasticsearch?  I am under the impression no.

Comment: @BjörnNilsson The snapshots are so we can do statistical analysis on the data for our accountants, etc.  Measure growth, attrition, etc.   We have considered doing readonly replicas, read the first (via sqlalchemy) store off the data in memory (via python), read the second store it in memory, and so on.  We do not want to paint ourselves into a corner though and 2 years from now when we have thousands of snapshots have a query that takes a few days to finish.

Comment: "would we be able to do the example query via elasticsearch" => Nothing's impossible! By carefully crafting a good data mapping, I'm pretty positive, something can be done, indeed. + you can keep all the snapshots you want, ES will happily ingest them.